# Wordpress theming: Wrapping entry titles?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a custom child theme for the Thematic Framework.

I'm having trouble with the alignment of my post titles. When they wrap onto a second line, they mess up the positioning of my date.

You can see an example here: http://everydaytype.com/wp

On the top entry, which is one line long, the date and the entry title are aligned.

On the second two following entries, the title wraps to a second line and displaces the date.

I've tried playing with the relative and absolute positioning of both the entry date and the entry title to no avail. I've tried playing with the height and the line height. I've tried display:inline variants.

I'm using Firebug to reveal the CSS that affects both elements, but haven't yet been able to make anything work.

My goal, to state it clearly, is to be able to have entry titles of any length and keep them aligned with the date like on the top entry.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to place the `<span class="entry-date">` **before** the `<h2>` in the html code itself. (in one of your theme files).

```
<span class="entry-date">...</span>
<h2 class="entry-title">...</h2>
```

then apply the following styles:

```
.entry-date {
   clear:both;
   display:block;
   font-family:Futura,sans-serif;
   height:0;
   padding-right:30px;
   position:relative;
   top:2em;
   width:60px;
 }
```

Comment: Agreed, you should modify your HTML so that the date comes first, followed by all the rest of the post content. Combined with the above styles, this should, at the very least, make it much easier to adjust your styling.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I'm struggling with the PHP aspect of the theme development in general, and I'm really only competent in HTML and CSS. I agree with your solutions if I were able to edit the HTML of the template, but editing the PHP is a much harder task. I looked in the files to see if I could figure out how to take the "date" part of the metadata of the post and put it above the title, but I don't understand the PHP involved. Is there away using purely CSS?

Comment: np! please mark the question as 'answered' if this is right. good luck coding!

Comment: I found an article and placed this : <span class="entry-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span> before the title in my post-template.php file, but it didn't change anything. I thought I would at least get some text. Is there any way to do this using purely CSS?